# Joining two Queries together in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two separate queries: **Employee** and **Manager**, which work perfectly fine and as I want but I wish to combine all the **COLUMNS** from both queries. Is this possible? I obviously don't expect a full answer but would appreciate some insight into possible methods to achieve this.

Employee Query:

```
SELECT
  shopTableRef.shopname AS "Shop Name:",
  perTableRef.personname AS "Employee Name:",
  COUNT(inStoreTableRef.payid) AS "Total Sales:",
  SUM(payTableRef.amount) AS "Sales Value (£):"
FROM
  fss_Person perTableRef
JOIN
  fss_Employee empTableRef ON perTableRef.personid = empTableRef.empid
JOIN
  fss_InstorePayment inStoreTableRef ON empTableRef.empid = inStoreTableRef.empid
JOIN
  fss_Payment payTableRef ON payTableRef.payid = inStoreTableRef.payid
JOIN
  fss_Shop shopTableRef ON payTableRef.shopid = shopTableRef.shopid
WHERE
  empTableRef.roleid = 2
GROUP BY
  perTableRef.personname
ORDER BY
  COUNT(inStoreTableRef.payid) DESC
```

Manager Query:

```
SELECT
  perTableRef.personname AS "Manager's Name:"
FROM
  fss_Person perTableRef
JOIN
  fss_Employee empTableRef ON perTableRef.personid = empTableRef.empid
JOIN
  fss_Manager manTableRef ON empTableRef.empid = manTableRef.empid
WHERE
  empTableRef.roleid = 1
GROUP BY
  perTableRef.personname
```

I have tried the following: UNION, UNION ALL, INNER JOIN, JOIN and nested queries but none seem to work.

Comment: Hope you'd have given alias name for the columns which are not present in Manager table, i.e. count of columns in case of UNION/ UNION ALL must be the same.

In Manager table's select list, add the following:
  NULL AS "Shop Name:" ,
  perTableRef.personname AS "Manager's Name:",
  NULL AS "Total Sales:",
  NULL AS "Sales Value (£):"

Add UNION between both the queries and check

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try this and again, it doesn't combine the columns but the rows and gives me several NULL values at the end of the combined table.

Comment: What exactly is your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION or UNION ALL should work with a couple of adjustments.

1. Each query must return the same number/type of columns, so fill in your Manager query with `NULL AS "Shop Name:"`, etc. for the missing columns.
2. Only one ORDER BY is allowed for the combined queries, so make sure that comes at the very end, and refer to the ordering column by its aliased name `"Total Sales:"`

Comment: Essentially the only column I'm wanting to add is the "Manager Name:" from the Manager query to the Employee one. Is there not a simpler way to do this?